# is sql server more efficient than a local database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, visual-studio

I was making a database application in vs with c#.
initially i was using a database created with sql server.My app.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=ARAVIND-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=businessdata;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.sqlClient" />


</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

After this i used a local database instead. I copied the database to the project solution.
Visual studio automatically configured the app.config.The new app.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Small_Business_Management.Properties.Settings.businessdataConnectionString1"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\businessdata.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


  </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

Now when i use this local database i noticed that it takes 1 to 2 seconds(sometimes even more)more to perform the operations than when i used a sql server database.Why is this performance difference?

Comment: (too) many possibilities...

Answer (score 4):

You really mix up two things here as SQL Server is a Software Piece that can run on a local Computer, too.

Point is, that your local Computer most likely SUCKS compared to a "real" database Server. Most people dont have workstations with tons of Memory and IO (though the IO side changes with SSD). SO, the question is not "local vs. non-local" but "Workstation vs. Server", and yes, a Server can be a LOT more powerful than a small local Workstation, depending on how it is technically set up. I have seen database Servers with 100+ cores, Terabytes of SSD Cache and more than hundred discs to handle the IO requirements.

On the negative side, obviously, a Server has to SEND you the data. Even with 1 Gigabit that is slower than an in Memory Transfer of a locally installed SQL Server. But that ONLY is relevant when (a) you pull a LOT of data and (b) you do not do heavy processing on that - which makes that more an academic case.

Now, in your case it gets even better. You do not even HAVE a local SQL Server install (or: do not use it), instead using LocalDb - that is clearly not a "Server Level" System. Localdb is an "improved express" ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx ) and express among other things is limited in resource usage (Memory, CPU). Your Server is likely a real Server, so it will use a LOT more rssources than Express can even hope to have, which is limited to:

- Limited to lesser of 1 Socket or 4 cores
- 1 GB

That is pretty pathetic by today's standards. Now, in the same terms - it is quite a lot a for smaller databases, and quite a LOT if the databases are small. But when you hit larger stuff - and then put a small db on it - things will fly.

So, it depends. Yes, a Server can be a LOT more powerful than a local machine.

Hope to get that right from the circumstances - another alternative would be you start both on the same machine, in this case it could simply be Startup time. LocalDb will IIRC Close the database when not in use, so regardless of Memory availability, it is "cold". SQL Server keeps the database active, so - it is "hot" (i.e. pages loaded are still in Memory, while localdb has to get them again from disc).

Many "it depends". Some "on your configuration".